# Cannot connect the oracle cloud database with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g, entity-framework-6

Did anyone succeed to connect the oracle cloud database with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess(ODP.NET ) ?
I already Connected oracle cloud with Oracle.DataAccess but some reason I need use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess for entity framework and heres the LOGS:

"Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-12570: Network Session: Unexpected packet read error ---> OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException: ORA-12570: Network Session: Unexpected packet read error ---> OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException: ORA-12537: Network Session: End of file"

My Config :

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
      <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
 <connectionStrings>        
<add name="ABC" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ABC.csdl|res://*/ABC.ssdl|res://*/ABC.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=CLOUD;PASSWORD=***;USER ID=ABC&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>        
<add name="ABCEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ABC.csdl|res://*/ABC.ssdl|res://*/ABC.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=CLOUD;PASSWORD=***;USER ID=ABC&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>      
</connectionStrings>    
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/></startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please provide some code while posting on this forum.

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: Which Database Cloud Service? We have more than one. For example, here's instructions for our Exadata Express Service http://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/exadata-express-cloud/csdbp/enabling-oracle-sqlnet-access-client-applications.html

Comment: Thanks your response and here's our environment 
PAAS : Data Management - Database
http://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/database-dbaas-cloud/index.html
DAAS : 11.2.0.4
IDE : VS2015
Now our problem is we can't connect to DAAS when we use ManagedDataAccess to built the connection but use DataAccess it can work .
Could it the ManagedDataAccess driver problem ?
This is the fist time we use cloud service and I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. very grateful